# grouping with linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
class Customer
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Order> OrderList { get; set; }
}

class Order
{
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public List<Item> ItemList { get; set; }
}

class Item
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("CustID");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("OrderNumber");
        dt.Columns.Add("ItemName");

        dt.Rows.Add("1", "A", "O1", "Item1");
        dt.Rows.Add("1", "A", "O1", "Item2");
        dt.Rows.Add("1", "A", "O1", "Item3");

        dt.Rows.Add("1", "A", "O2", "Item4");
        dt.Rows.Add("1", "A", "O2", "Item5");

        dt.Rows.Add("1", "A", "O3", "Item1");

        dt.Rows.Add("2", "B", "O4", "Item1");
        dt.Rows.Add("2", "B", "O4", "Item2");

        dt.Rows.Add("2", "B", "O5", "Item3");


        dt.AcceptChanges();

        List<DataRow> dList = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();


        //This is not working
        var qry = dList.GroupBy(x => x["CustID"])
                        .Select(g => new Customer
                        {
                            ID = g.Key.ToString(),
                            Name = g.First()["Name"].ToString(),
                            OrderList = g.GroupBy(t=> t["OrderNumber"]).Select(x => new Order
                            {

                                OrderNumber = x.First()["OrderNumber"].ToString(),
                                ItemList = g.GroupBy(u => u["OrderNumber"]).Select(y => new Item { ItemName = y.First()["ItemName"].ToString() }).ToList()
                            }).ToList()
                        }).ToList();
    }
```

I am trying to get output like this

```
Custtomer.Name="A"
Customer.ID="1"
Customer.OrderList = ListOfOrders with "01", "02", "03"
Customer.OrderList[0].ItemList = ListOfItems with that order Item1, Item2, Item3


Custtomer.Name="B"
Customer.ID="2"
Customer.OrderList = ListOfOrders with "04", "05"
Customer.OrderList[0].ItemList = ListOfItems with that order Item4, Item5
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong with my qry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you're trying to use `x` within the `Select` call, but it's out of scope. Also, you're trying to use the `Name` directly, but it's not part of the grouping key. Finally, you're trying to select a single order in your Select, not a group of them. I think you want this:

```
var qry = dList.GroupBy(x => new { CustID = (string) x["CustID"],
                                   Name = (string) x["Name"] })
               .Select(g => new Customer {
                          ID = g.Key.CustID,
                          Name = g.Key.Name,
                          OrderList = g.Select(x => new Order {
                                 // Indentation bad to avoid scrolling!
                                 OrderNumber = (string) x["OrderNumber"] })
                                       .ToList()
                       })
               .ToList();
```

Assuming that CustID is unique (so you'll get the same Name each time) you can group just by CustID and then take the first customer for the Name, as per Achim's answer - but personally I prefer to group all the "per customer" data in the key, as that's *logically* what you're grouping on.

EDIT: To answer the edited question, you *could* populate the `OrderList` property something like this:

```
OrderList = g.GroupBy(t=> (string) t["OrderNumber"]).Select(x => new Order
{
    OrderNumber = x.Key,
    ItemList = x.Select(y => new Item { 
                              ItemName = (string) y["ItemName"]
                        }).ToList()
}).ToList()
```

... but to be honest it's getting pretty messy by then.

Comment: I have to group on CustID only and still access Name. There are 30 fields in real scenario that has to be selected while grouping is done on the basis of one field.

Comment: @Asdfg: If you're only grouping on a single field, then *which* entry do you want to use for the Name field? Two entries with the same CustID could have different Name values... which name do you want?

Comment: How come you guys are able to write such cool queries. Is there any tool that does it? What am i failing to understand about LINQ that is stopping me to write such queries? What if i write traditional ForEach loop? Will that be bad programming because i think internally LINQ does the same thing. Am i wrong?

Comment: @Asdfg: Just experience, I suspect. I've written quite a lot of LINQ queries :) Writing foreach loops is fine, when you're wanting to take an action on each iteration - but if you're effectively just computing a value / collection, LINQ provides a more declarative approach.

Comment: then i guess i will keep coming back here for LINQ help till i gain expert level knowledge.

Comment: small change here. What if i have List of Items property inside Order class and i want to have items collection populated for each order. I tried altering the query but it doesnt give the correct result. Please check the question for the altered query.

Comment: @Asdfg: I've edited the answer... but I think it's best if you add any *extra* questions as new ones, rather than making this one more and more complicated.

Comment: Awesome. Many thanks. I can say i am learning a lot with your help while getting the job done.

Answer (score 1):

```
var qry = dList.GroupBy(x => x["CustID"]).Select(g => new Customer
        {
            ID = g.Key.ToString(),
            Name = g.First()["Name"],
            OrderList=g.Select(o => new List<Order>(new Order{ OrderNumber=o["OrderNumber"]}))
        }).ToList();
```